# how to extract a different substring for each row of a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with putative alignments of thousands of probe sequences. I would like to pull out the adjacent nucleotide from the genome for each alignment. My dataframe includes `seq.name` for the target chromosome and I've added an `adjacent_pos` variable with the location on the target chromosome that I want. Using `read.fasta` from the phylotools package gives me a genome in the format of a dataframe with `seq.name` and `seq.text` for each chromosome and unplaced scaffold.

Working on a test data set with a single chromosome, I successfully used something like this:

```
adj <- cbind(alignments$adjacent_pos, alignments$adjacent_pos)
alignments$adjacent_base <- str_sub(genome$seq.text, adj)
```

Now back to the whole genome, I can't wrap my head around how to direct `str_sub` to the correct `seq.name` for each `seq.position`. I'm sure there's an elegant solution, but I haven't been able to find it!

Comment: please can you provide a small reproducible example for your `alignments` and `genome` objects? the `merge()` function from the *data.table* package will surely help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your file looks like this:

```
cat test.fa
>chr01
ACCGGTT
>chr02
ATGCATGC
```

Something like what you have done, to read in the fasta and extract the sequence. Key part is creating a GenomicRanges object:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
library(BSgenome)
library(Biostrings)

adj <- data.frame(chr=c("chr01","chr02"),start=c(2,3),end=c(2,3))

    chr start end
1 chr01     2   2
2 chr02     3   3

adj = makeGRangesFromDataFrame(adj)

fasta <- readDNAStringSet("test.fa")
SEQ = getSeq(fasta,makeGRangesFromDataFrame(adj))

as.character(SEQ)
[1] "C" "G"
```

or if the fasta file is huge, you can use Rsamtools, indexing the fasta file first:

```
library(Rsamtools)
fasta = FaFile("test.fa")
indexFa('test.fa')

as.character(getSeq(FaFile("test.fa"),adj))
chr01 chr02 
  "C"   "G"
```

Comment: but it's not just one location from each chromosome. I have about 160k alignments, each needing a different location pulled out from a 3G genome that has 21 chromosomes plus over 7500 unplaced scaffolds. Still perhaps the GenomicRanges object is the way to go?

Comment: yes.. the code above works for as many locations as you have. You just need to construct the genomic ranges object like I did above, and I suggest using the Rsamtools solution if your file is huge

Comment: ```adj``` should be GenomicRanges object...if it was clear from the solution above

Comment: thank you I will try

Comment: brilliant, worked like a charm! thank you

Comment: you're welcome :) glad it worked for you